# Identify first letter from every word in a TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I tried to create a unique code for each shop in the form I made. I have two TextBox controls (`TBNameStore` and `TBCodeStore`). What I want is that when I write the name of the shop, for example *"Brothers in Arm"*, in `TBNameStore`, then `TBCodeStore` should automatically be filled with the text *"BIA"*.

How can I do that?

Comment: Look at `split` function by space and `substring` function

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: @pasty for now i dont have any clue about my case.. for now iam trying to learn about  split and substring function.. like Giorgi Nakeuri say..

Comment: What if you had one shop named "Brothers in Arm" and another named "Big Indigo Armchairs"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton i will add number in the end of code.. like BIA001 and auto search in database for same code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I write a code that can help you with your problem.

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
    Public Function GetInitials(ByVal MyText As String) As String
        Dim Initials As String = ""
        Dim AllWords() As String = MyText.Split(" "c)
        For Each Word As String In AllWords
            If Word.Length > 0 Then
                Initials = Initials & Word.Chars(0).ToString.ToUpper
            End If
        Next
        Return Initials
    End Function
    Private Sub TBNameStore_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TBNameStore.TextChanged
        TBCodeStore.Text = GetInitials(TBNameStore.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Like you can see, the GetInitials get you all the first letter of all the words in the text.

Comment: Your code works fine and no error at all , and easy to understand for me .. thank you .. you have saved my time .. :D

Comment: @GreenFire Perfect! Note that my intention was not to bully you but rather make your improve you answer. Also note that you don't have to include the option strict statement because it's very easy to see if this option is off/on by looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using the mentioned `Split` and `SubString` methods and [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx) could look like this:

- create a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) where every first character of each word is stored
- separate the words using the specified delimiter (default is empty space) using the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method
- convert the array to list in order to apply the LINQ-ToList extension => [ToList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- for each found word => ForEach(sub (word as String) ...
- take the first character from the word, convert it to upper case and put it in the result
  => result.Append(word.[SubString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(0, 1).[ToUpper()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
- return the result as string => result.ToString()

The code looks like this:

```
private function abbreviation(input as String, optional delimiter as String = " ")
    dim result = new StringBuilder()
    input.Split(delimiter) _ 
        .ToList()         _
        .ForEach(sub (word as String)
                    result.Append(word.SubString(0, 1).ToUpper()) 
                end sub)
    return result.ToString()

end function
```

Usage:

```
dim s = "Brothers in Arms"
Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", s, abbreviation(s))
```

and the output looks like expected:

```
Brothers in Arms => BIA
```